# Update same data from the same table depending on a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a similar case of a table, Like the case of this link [Update same data from the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65837001/update-same-data-from-the-same-table/65839953#65839953)
but in my case it must update depending on the column "dependency". In other words, it updates the repetitions in the tables always leaving the most recent line and for table that only have one line it does not update. My data is like this:
 [image]

I want it to be updated like this:
[image]

I tryed this code:

```
create table dbo.test( id int, CAR varchar(30), ACTIVE int, dependency int)
    
 insert into dbo.test(id, CAR, ACTIVE, dependency)
 values 


(1, 'AAA-25-35', 0,1),
(2, 'LDB-25-35', 0,2),
(3, 'LDB-00-35', 0,2),
(4, 'LDB-25-35', 0,2),
(5, 'LDB-00-35', 0,2),
(6, 'LDC-10-10', 0,2),
(7, 'LDC-10-10', 0,2),
(8, 'LDB-00-35', 0,2),
(9, 'AAA-25-35', 0,1),
(10, 'AAA-25-35', 0,3),
(11, 'AAA-25-35', 0,3),
(12, 'BBB-25-35', 0,2),
(13, 'BBB-25-35', 0,3),
(14, 'BBB-25-35', 0,3)

GO 
SELECT * FROM TEST


WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAR ORDER BY ID) AS t,
         CAR,
         ACTIVE
  FROM Test
)

UPDATE CTE
SET ACTIVE = 1
WHERE t=1
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CTE c WHERE c.CAR = CTE.CAR GROUP BY CAR HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

go
SELECT * FROM  test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAR, dependency ORDER BY ID) AS t,
         LEAD(id) OVER (PARTITION BY CAR, dependency ORDER BY ID) as next_id,
         CAR,
         ACTIVE
  FROM Test
)
UPDATE CTE
SET ACTIVE = 1
WHERE t = 1 AND next_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Illustrious, an issue that was not verified, he is not updating the column "ACTIVE" to the column "CAR" which is reflected in the same "DEPENDENCY". You can check the CAR = 'LDB-00-35', you should update two first lines and leave one. The code did the reverse.

Comment: Look at this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ab8fc1c689352abb3e34704bef9680a0). The result is exactly the same as the output described in the question.

Comment: I was able to solve it, I removed the update condition
"WHERE t = 1 AND next_id IS NOT NULL" and left only "WHERE next_id IS NOT NULL"

I was wrong to share the first result. Thank you for your attention.